# Android CoordinatorLayout anchor glitch with keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to use a `CoordinatorLayout` to anchor a view to another one and it is working almost perfectly. The problem is that when i switch to another fragment, open the keyboard, then switch back, the anchored view gets messed up. Sometimes after a couple seconds it (seemingly) randomly snaps back into place. Here is a gif to demonstrate what I am talking about.

[image]

As you can see, the `FloatingActionButton` is not aligned when I return to the fragment, but after a while it snaps back into place. What could cause this issue?

**Fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout_main"
                                             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <!-- Other views -->

    <!-- Bottom sheet -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_primes"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` attribute in your activity tag of the activity in question in the AndroidManifest.xml file.